# How to test the type of Date.getTime()

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following code:

```
let date1 = new Date("January 13, 2018 11:00:00");
console.log(date1.getTime());

console.log(typeof date1.getTime() === Number);
console.log(typeof date1.getTime());
console.log(typeof date1.getTime() === number);
```

Which prints:

```
1515841200000
false
number
ReferenceError: number is not defined
    at eval:31:40
    at eval
    at new Promise
```

So it looks like `typeof date1.getTime()` is `number`. However, when I test the equality with `number` I get an error, and when I test the equality with `Number` I get `false`.

The reason I want to test the type is that I have a Jest test, where I am checking if a variable is a `Number`:

```
expect.any(Number)
```

However, the test gets a variable from a statement like `date1.getTime()` and the test is failing instead of passing.

So how could I test the type such that `date1.getTime()` would not make the test fail?

Comment: `console.log(typeof date1.getTime() === 'number');`returns `true`.

Comment: How are you using `expect.any(Number)`? According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectanyconstructor) "_You can use it inside `toEqual` or `toBeCalledWith`_"

Comment: I'm using it inside `toEqual`

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(typeof date1.getTime() === 'number')` since `typeof` operator returns a string.

Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

You can use this in your assertion: `expect(typeof date1.getTime()).toBe('number')`

Comment: What about `expect(typeof date1.getTime()).toBe('number');` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
expect(date1.getDate()).toEqual(expect.any(Number));
```